# CREATE SCHEMA o DATABASE tiene alguna diferencia? y colocar el CONSTRAINT antes de una FK es necesario?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Tengo esas dudas en SQL.. es un lenguaje no tan estricto y corre a pesar de las distintas maneras de escribirlo.. Cual es exactamente la diferencia entre CREATE SCHEMA y CREATE DATEBASE cuando me puse a ver el codigo generado por Workbech este trabaja con SCHEMA y de veras que me tiene algo mariado esa palabra.. toda mi corta vida de estudio de sql habia sido DATABASE :S

Por otra parte aprovechando la pregunta.. tambien el Workbench hace uso del CONSTRAINT delante del FOREIGNKEY

Aqui un ejemplo de codigo generado por Workbench

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tallermecanico_hd`.`e_vehiculos` (
`placa` INT NOT NULL,
`marca` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
`modelo` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
`anio` VARCHAR(4) NULL,
`observ` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
`serial` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
`color` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
`puertas` INT,
`motor` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
`transmision` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
//<<<aqui yo colocaria el campo foraneo cedula_c pero workbench no lo hizo<<<
PRIMARY KEY (`placa`),
CONSTRAINT `cedula_c`
FOREIGN KEY ()
REFERENCES `tallermecanico_hd`.`c_clientes` ()
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Yo estaba acostumbrado en el Foreignkey solo colocar asi:

```
FOREINGN KEY(cedula_c)REFERENCES c_clientes
```

y  si funciona igual pero cual es la diferencia D: que hace el CONSTRAINT??? Ademas el Workbench usa el nombredebasededatos.nombredetabla ademas que no coloco nada dentro del parentesis de references y no crea el campo foraneo cedula_c

Como busco el tema de los puntos... [db].[table] como se llama eso ese punto es igual que poner FROM o algo parecido? eso tiene algun nombre para buscar bien ese tema que nadie me lo dio >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondo a tu primera pregunta solamente. Creo que, de acuerdo a las normas del sitio, es mejor hacer una pregunta por caso, porque es más útil para un futuro y porque responder a varias preguntas podría requerir demasiado esfuerzo y la misma pregunta podría ser cerrada por considerarse demasiado amplia.

Entonces:

> Cual es exactamente la diferencia entre CREATE SCHEMA y CREATE
>   DATEBASE

La diferencia *exacta* es una sola, que se llaman diferente, pero hacen lo mismo. Así lo afirma la documentación de MySQL:

> `CREATE DATABASE` creates a database with the given name. To use this
>   statement, you need the `CREATE` privilege for the database. `CREATE SCHEMA` is a synonym for `CREATE DATABASE`.
>
> ---
>
> `CREATE DATABASE`
>   crea una base de datos con el nombre dado. Para utilizar esta
>   declaración, es necesario el privilegio `CREATE` para la base de datos. **`CREATE SCHEMA` es sinónimo de `CREATE DATABASE`**.
>
> [<sub>`CREATE DATABASE`en la documentación de MySQL</sub>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-database.html)

También en el glosario de MySQL se dice lo siguiente:

> #### schema
>
> Conceptualmente, un `schema` es un conjunto interrelacionado de
>   objetos de bases de datos, tales como tablas, columnas de tablas,
>   tipos de datos de las columnas, índices, claves externas, y así
>   sucesivamente. Estos objetos están conectados a través de la sintaxis
>   SQL, debido a que las columnas representan las tablas, las claves
>   externas se refieren a tablas y columnas, y así sucesivamente.
>   Idealmente, están conectados lógicamente en cuanto que trabajan juntos
>   como parte de una aplicación unificada o marco flexible. Por ejemplo,
>   en las bases de datos `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` y `performance_schema`
>   utilizan "`schema`" en sus nombres para destacar las estrechas
>   relaciones entre las tablas y columnas que contienen.
>
> **En MySQL, físicamente, `schema` y `database` son sinónimos, por lo que en la sintaxis SQL puede usar la palabra clave `SCHEMA` en lugar
>   de `DATABASE`, por ejemplo, en lugar de utilizar `CREATE SCHEMA` puede
>   usar `CREATE DATABASE`.**
>
> Algunos otros productos de base de datos establecen una distinción.
>   Por ejemplo, en el producto de base de datos Oracle, un `schema` sólo
>   representa una parte de un diagrama de base de datos: las tablas y
>   otros objetos propiedad de un único usuario.
>
> [<sub>`schema` en el glosario de MySQL</sub>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_schema)

P. D.: Creo que la otra pregunta deberías plantearla aparte, obtendrás mejores respuestas y será más útil al resto de la comunidad de SO.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias .. es que me pareció que la primera pregunta no era mucho y son algo similares las preguntas..  ademas que tenia que esperar algo de tiempo para la siguiente  jeje pero hare caso a tu sugerencia. :)